# array index out of bounds exception for no reason

Tags: java

I am getting array index out of bounds exception at the last line of the prog, 
`output[1][1]` generates such an exception there. But the same thing remained normal in the previous loop.

```
{  
    int ict=66,total_slots=12,h1=15,index_count=65;
    String output[][] = new String[ict][total_slots+1];

    for (int x = 0; x < (ict); x++)
        output[x][0] = Integer.toString(x);
    for (int y = 0; y < (total_slots + 1); y++)
        output[0][y] = Integer.toString(y);
    for (int x = 1; x <= (index_count); x++ )
        for (int y = 1; y <= (total_slots); y++)
            output[x][y] = "n";

    for (int x=1; x <= h1; x++) {
        output[x][1]="y";//exception occurs here
        limit[x]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please pay more attention to the formatting of your code - it's *really* hard to understand without any indentation. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: What is the value of h1?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: Hopefully mine does :)

Comment: What are the values of `index_count`, `h1`  and `limit`

Comment: Remember that array indexes start at 0. and go up to length-1, read my answer for more details

Comment: int index_count=65, h1=15;//first line of my code

Answer (score 1):

Remember when you declare an array like `String output[][]=new String[5][5];` then `output[4][4]` is the last element you can access since array indexes start at 0

you have declared your array as:

```
String output[][] = new String[ict][total_slots+1];
```

in your for loop you have

```
for( int x=1; x<=(ict); x++ )
    for( int y=1; y<=(total_slots); y++)
         output[x][y]="n";
```

On the very last iteration of the outer loop and the very first iteration of the inner loop, you are trying to access `output[ict][0]` which is what throws the exception. Remember that since 0 is the first index, `ict - 1` will be the last valid index for the first dimension.

Try this:

```
String output[][] = new String[ict][total_slots]; //this is cleaner

for( int x=0; x<ict; x++ )
    for( int y=0; y<total_slots; y++)
         output[x][y]="n";
```

This way the last iteration of the outer loop would only go up to `ict - 1`

edit: 
It seems you have edited the question significantly. Please do not edit your question in the future in response to answers, because this will only confuse new readers.

As your code stands right now, the only error (compile time no less, irrelevant to exceptions) is the fact that `limit[x]++;` is invalid because `limit` has not been declared in this scope. otherwise the code is legal and runs fine.

Comment: The array is declared with `total_slots + 1`, so `<=` acually work right. Bad style anyways to declare it with +1 and use <=.

Comment: I stand corrected, he declared the first dimension wrong though. editing answer

Comment: Hey ForeverStudent! Thanks for ur effort, but I am not getting exception at the line u have explained. output[][]="n" with two for loop works clearly. At the next loop, when output[1][1] is accessed, their occurs the exception.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in response to answers, it will only confuse future readers

Answer (score 1):

```
    {  
        int ict=66,total_slots=12,h1=15,index_count=65;
..................................................
..................................................
        for (int x=1; x <= h1; x++) {
                output[x][1]="y";//exception occurs here
                limit[x]++;
            }
        }
```

At the last for loop, you recieve ArryIndexOutOfBoundsException , while trying to access the element output[13][1] cause your array width is only 13 i.e max index will be 12 but not more than that

Use total_slots instead of h1

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting array index out of bounds exception at the last line of the prog, output[1][1] generates such an exception there.

Recheck the console output. You must have mistaken the erroring line, since there is no way to generate such an exception. The problem most probably lies in the `limit[]`, which we don't know how it's declared.

Btw, the last line is `limit[x]++` ;)