# Index out of bounds on a callback

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback

---

Simplified question to my problem:

My new - more informed - issue is that my openGames.get(position) is returning null

So here is my callback:

```
public interface WagerCallback {
    void onCallback(String wager);
}
```

.

```
public void getWager(int position, final WagerCallback wagerCallback) {
    FCGames.child(openGames.get(position)).child("wager").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            wagerr = (double) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String wagerD = Double.toString(wagerr);
            wage = wagerD.endsWith("0");

            wagerCallback.onCallback(wagerD);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

FCGames is defined as:
    public DatabaseReference FCGames = database.getReference("FCGames");

And my openGames.get(position) is a list that is a part of a RecyclerView adapter. So in my recycler view, I have this defined:

```
String userName = mData.get(position);
```

Which is synonymous to my openGames definition, it just isn't written out. What this does is it stores the userName of the person who created a game as the index of the game.

This userName is also the name of the node stored in the firebase, like this:

[image]

So my issue is that for some reason, openGames.get(position), in this case is returning null and I am not sure why. I am using get(position) in a very similar manner where it works in my RecyclerView class like this:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    String userName = mData.get(position);
    holder.userName.setText(userName);
    holder.bind(mData.get(position), position, listener);

    fcl.getWager(position, new FlipCoinLobby.WagerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(String wager) {
            holder.wager.setText(wager);
        }
    });

}
```

So for example, in the line

```
String username = mData.get(position);
```

That line is using the get(position) function and it is working, but just a few lines below that it is not working in my callback.

I hope this is a bit more clear of a question and I can get some help.

This is my error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

IF things were working perfectly at the moment, then

```
openGame.get(position) = Brent_MB;
```

But that is currently not the case

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: edited my posts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array index out of bounds exception for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906191/array-index-out-of-bounds-exception-for-no-reason)

Comment: @Bruno The solution to that question does not apply to this problem. Is there anyway to remove the duplicate question?

Comment: At which particular line of code does that error occur? And what are the values of `FCGames` and `openGames.get(position)`? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry I totally forgot to tag you. I added those values to the bottom of the post.

Comment: Can you be more specific where have you added those values?

Comment: @AlexMamo bottom of the post, I sent that comment before adding them, didn't know you would respond so quickly :)

Comment: Your references look correct to me. At which **particular** line of code are you geeting that error? Paste it here.

Comment: @AlexMamo `FCGames.child(openGames.get(position)).child("wager").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`

Comment: So it's obvious that `openGames.get(position)` does **not** hold this value `Brent_MB`. Try to hardcode this value in your reference instead of `openGames.get(position)`, does it work?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yeah you are right, it doesn work if I just hardcode Brent_MB. However, I do need it to be openGames.get(position) as that value changes. I do not know why openGames.get(position) does not work in this case because I am using it in a way that seems fine to me. I will (in the next minute) post another relevant method that makes it seem like openGames.get(position) should be working here.

Comment: Hi @brentB, are you sure `openGames` is null?

Comment: There are too many disjunct pieces of code here for me to digest quickly. For example, what is the value of `openGames.get(position)`? It's easier to help if you reproduce the problem in a single, stand-alone piece of code (i.e. with hard-coded values, instead of variables). For more on this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just updated my question so hopefully it is a lot more clear and easy to follow - I may have not succeeded at this but I tried my best lol

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated my question to make it more easy to follow, I hope

Comment: @AlexMamo if I post another question that incorporates all of the same code as posted here, will it be marked as duplicate or do you think I am good to post another question? - It will be a slightly different question though

Comment: If you are sure is a slightly different question, then post it.